# Why do these enemies add bonus damage to their longbow attacks?

Tags: damage, pathfinder-2e, npc, adventure-path

**This question contains minor spoilers for the Kingmaker adventure path**

I am using the new version of the Kingmaker adventure path (the one released for Pathfinder 2e). During the rushlight tournaments first competition, the archery competition, you are expected to shoot at targets and overcome their hardness, using only a normal, nonmagical longbow (page 339). When looking at the stats of the competitors, I saw that they all have a static bonus to their damage rolls, which is immensely useful in this competition, as

> you need to beat the hardness of the targets, and the hardness values are 2, 6 or 10

But with a normal longbow, this should not be the case. Now I know that "monsters" do not necessarily adhere to the same rules as pcs do, but in this case, this seems like an extreme advantage the npcs have in this competition. This leads me to believe that this is actually meant to be a composite longbow (even though the npcs would still have pretty high damage bonuses, as a composite bow only adds half your strength modifier and the npcs have +4 or even +6), instead of a normal longbow, especially considering that

> the hardness of the last target is 10, which would mean that even with a critical you don't have that big of a chance to actually surpass that, and it would be impossible with a normal hit)

Is there a rule I am missing about adding any kind of bonus to your damage with a normal long bow, or ist this simply an advantage given to the npcs?

Comment: I guess only the best archers are participating in that competition?

Comment: I mean, kind of (with one exception that ist explicitly called out in the book), but that still should not mean that they are playing by completely different rules as the players.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Weapon Specialization will provide some extra damage.

At the level that your party will participate in the Rushlight Tournament, they'll at least have [Weapon Specialization](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=7)*, which provides a +2 bonus to their damage (possibly higher if they're a fighter, or have Master in longbows some other way). The longbow's Deadly d10 trait will also trigger on a critical hit, which would be combined with the normal damage of the weapon for the purpose of overcoming  Hardness.

*The linked version is for Fighter, but all classes get this feature and it works the same for all of them.

Comment: The values of the NPCs are still pretty high for weapon Focus (there ist one with 4, which ist possible with only weapon foucs, but there ist also one with +6), but yeah, thats at least one Thing I was missing, thanks.